# Different IDEs running identical code differently

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, intellij-idea, netbeans

I have the following code:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thready howdy = new Thready();
        Thread howYouDo = new Thread(howdy);
        howYouDo.start();
    }
}
class Thready implements Runnable{

    int hi = 1;

    public Thready(){}

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(++hi);
        }
    }
}
```

It runs fine in IntelliJ regardless of the @Override annotation. In Eclipse, it forces you to remove the @Override annotation, and it works. In NetBeans, it warns you to add an  @Override annotation, and the code runs, but the THREAD IS NEVER STARTED in NetBeans no matter what. Meaning the console does not print out anything.

What is going on?

Comment: My Eclipse is like NetBean, in that it warns you that you should add `@Override`. If your Eclipse tells you to remove it, then it is somehow running in Java 1.4 mode (or earlier).

Comment: Warnings about the `@Override` annotation are probably related to the Java version that projects in each IDE default to.  Off the top of my head, `@Override` for interface methods was added in 1.6.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede `@Override` javadoc says "Since 1.5".

Comment: Try making the main thread wait for the other thread to end, i.e. add `howYouDo.join();` after the `start()` call.

Comment: @Andreas IIRC, it was introduced in 1.5 but could not be applied to implementations of interface methods until 1.6.

Comment: @Andreas This is ___not___ necessary. OP doesn't start a daemon thread.